# CakePHP 3 Composer Installation Error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to create a project as shown in the official [Bookmarker Tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html#getting-cakephp) using the following command:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app bookmarker
```

Then I see the following errors:

> [RuntimeException]
>   Could not load package cakephp/migrations in http://packagist.org:
>   [UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint >=0.4.2
>   <1.0: Invalid version string "0.4.2 <1.0"
>
> [UnexpectedValueException]
>   Could not parse version constraint >=0.4.2 <1.0: Invalid version
>   string "0.4.2 <1.0"

Then I run `bin/cake server` and see the following errors:

> PHP Warning: 
>   require(/Library/WebServer/Documents/bookmarker/vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/bookmarker/config/bootstrap.php on line
>   23 PHP Stack trace: PHP   1. {main}()
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/bookmarker/bin/cake.php:0 PHP   2.
>   include() /Library/WebServer/Documents/bookmarker/bin/cake.php:31
>
> Warning:
>   require(/Library/WebServer/Documents/bookmarker/vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/bookmarker/config/bootstrap.php on line
>   23
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0010     227136   1. {main}() /Library/WebServer/Documents/bookmarker/bin/cake.php:0
>       0.0021     237624   2. include('/Library/WebServer/Documents/bookmarker/config/bootstrap.php')
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/bookmarker/bin/cake.php:31
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   '/Library/WebServer/Documents/bookmarker/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.21/lib/php') in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/bookmarker/config/bootstrap.php on line
>   23 PHP Stack trace: PHP   1. {main}()
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/bookmarker/bin/cake.php:0 PHP   2.
>   include() /Library/WebServer/Documents/bookmarker/bin/cake.php:31
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/Library/WebServer/Documents/bookmarker/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.21/lib/php') in
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/bookmarker/config/bootstrap.php on line
>   23
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0010     227136   1. {main}() /Library/WebServer/Documents/bookmarker/bin/cake.php:0
>       0.0021     237624   2. include('/Library/WebServer/Documents/bookmarker/config/bootstrap.php')
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/bookmarker/bin/cake.php:31

My system is OS X Yosemite 10.10.2, my PHP version is 5.5.21 and intl extension is enabled.

Are there anyone who had this issue or similar? Any solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run following command first (you might need to prepend this with `sudo` if composer was installed globally)

```
composer self-update
```

then again

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app bookmarker
```

Comment: Tried this. Vendor/autoload.php is still missing for me. Console error: the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system. I'm trying to run it on my MAMP server and this module is installed I assume it's checking the Mac OSX apache server for this info? Would this corrupt the installation though?

Comment: @woodscreative Are you sure that `intl` extension is enabled in `php.ini`?

Comment: @Alik yes its enabled in MAMP but I guess the problem is that composer does not recognise MAMP only the bundled apache/php with OSX.

Comment: @woodscreative MAMP's php folder should be the first folder on `PATH` or you can invoke `composer` with MAMP's php directly: `/path/to/mamp/php composer.phar ...` Anyway I think It would be better to google for `MAMP`, `composer`, `intl` to find a solution or ask for help here, on SO, in your own question. Your problem is not the same as OP had.

Comment: Hi Alik, that was useful thanks edited bash/path to php to use MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

The latest way to install CakePHP 3.2 is:

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app bookmarker
```

First find out which version of PHP you are using, and find out where it is located.

```
> php -v
PHP 5.5.34 (cli) (built: Apr 22 2016 19:16:58) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

> which php
/usr/bin/php
```

You need to have php version 7 as the primary one.  I know of two options for you.

1. Copy the MAMP php file over to replace your /usr/bin/php file (you may also want to back it up.

   (sudo mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php5.5.34; sudo cp /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin /usr/bin/php)
2. Order your system $PATH variable to the MAMP path for your php7 bin directory. You can also add this line to your ~/.profile so it will load every time you start the terminal.

   export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin:$PATH";

Once these changes are made, you should be able to install cake without a problem, and your cake bake commands should also work.

Answer (score -2):

if you go into your app folder and run

```
composer install
```

it might fix it.

If fix it for me!

Thanks