# cakephp 3 failed to open vendor/autoload.php after cloning a git repository

Tags: php, git, cakephp

I have a git repository which is a simple cakephp3 application. (i cant share because that is private).
i forked the repository and cloned it to my local directory, but as i open the url it gives me this error:

```html
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\shopinator\sms\smsv3\vendor\autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\shopinator\sms\smsv3\config\bootstrap.php on line 23 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening
required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\shopinator\sms\smsv3\vendor\autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\shopinator\sms\smsv3\config\bootstrap.php on line 23
```

I also have composer installed and is recognizable. I'm using git bash.

the same repository is running fine on another machine.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**
I've tried it this way:
I'm installing cakephp 3 using composer, it still gives me the same error.

```
composer create-project cakephp/app
```

I've also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913693/cakephp-3-composer-installation-error) but no luck.

**Update:**

with this command

```
 composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app
```

the fresh installation worked.

Comment: try composer dumpautoload.. might solve the problem

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

Comment: it says PluginInstaler is not auto loadable, cannot call post-auto-load dump script

Comment: You don't need that script to run, it's probably [an older version of the one in the core](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/src/Console/Installer.php), you can _probably_ delete those references from the composer file. You're effectively asking how to install someone else's app - you should ask "someone else", your problems are not applicable to a wider audience, and the code you're talking about isn't in the question, or accessible.

Comment: i'm facing the same error for simple cakephp 3 install with composer

Comment: I doubt it's the same error but If you are - you should ask about and fix that first. Any problem you have with a standard install is going to apply to a specific install.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've solved the problem.
I downloaded the composer.phar file from [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/)
and executed the following commands in my application root.

```
php composer.phar install
```

Now i don't have that autoload.php issues.

Comment: Thanks! It is not solving error for me, But help in debug issue. displays name of missing plugins which are necessary. Save the day!